# how to get the store name in CMS page - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have multistore. `1. shoes.com`, `2. shirt.com`

Both of them have the same content, but the only difference is the **name** of the store `(i.e shoes.com and shirt.com)`

I don't want to create the same pages just for multiple store.
Is there a way, we can use the same page and use some code, might be like this `{{storename}}`, and its render on front-end.

Answer (score 1):

In phtml:

**Gets the current store's name**

```
$storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

In Cms:

**Gets the current store's name**

```
{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}
```

Nb: dont forget to config the name of your store in : **admin->system->configuration, general->store information** select the store in top left corner and set the name of your store that you want to show.